# how to convert jquery datepicker format to timestamp format like dd-mm-yyyy (28/09/2019 3:40pm)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> I dont wanna manual convertion, i have the jquery datepicker v.1.12.1
>   if i select the date from datepicker it will automatically convert  timestamp format.
>   i want a date format in **timestamp** like **28/09/2019 3:40 GMT-0400** this format to **1569668513** this format.

Can you please help me?

```js
var dateString = '#referdate',
    dateTimeParts = dateString.split(' '),
    timeParts = dateTimeParts[1].split(':'),
    dateParts = dateTimeParts[0].split('/'),
    date;

date = new Date(dateParts[2], parseInt(dateParts[1], 10) - 1, dateParts[0], timeParts[0], timeParts[1]);

console.log(date.getTime()); //1379426880000
console.log(date); //28-09-2019 3:40 GMT-0400
```

Comment: date has other methods ... like [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) - when in doubt, *read the friendly manual*

Comment: but sir, i using the jquery datepicker, if i select the date from datepicker it will automatically convert timestamp format.

Comment: what is `timestamp format`? is the result a Date object? your code doesn't make sense since `dateString = '#referdate'` means that `dateString.split(' ')` will return an array of length 1 with the value `"#referdate"` - perhaps you need to do some more explaining

Comment: im using jquery datepicker, if i select the date from datepicker i want to  automatically convert timestamp format. how?

Comment: What is this timestamp format you keep going on about

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <script>
          function getTimeAndDate(){
          let today = new Date();
                let date = today.getDate()+'/' + (today.getMonth()+1) + '/'+today.getFullYear();
                let h = today.getHours();
                let m =today.getMinutes();
            console.log(h+':'+m);
            console.log(date);
          }
          
       </script>
       <body>
          <input type="button" onclick="getTimeAndDate()" value="Button">
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: im using jquery datepicker, if i select the date from datepicker i want to  automatically convert timestamp format. how?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the `dateFormat` option?

From the [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "@"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input id="datepicker">
```

Comment: same but i want timestamp format.. if i select any dates from datepicker i want to get like 28/09/2019 to 1569668513 this format.

Comment: thanks a lot @ArleighHix, but i want to show this conversion on my console only.. in frontend i want to show date and time only..

Comment: @Joe that was not clear at all from your question or any other comments, see my new answer, and add your comment above to the question please.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to log the timestamp of the chosen date, you can get the javascript date object directly from the picker on change.

```js
// however you initialize the datepicker does not matter
$("#datepicker").datepicker();

// when a date is picked the change event is fired
$("#datepicker").change(function() {
  // get the date object
  let theDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
  
  console.log(theDate.getTime())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input id="datepicker">
```